# Blend a clipped image together with a background into destination in one step

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, direct3d

Please have a look at this image.

[image: Expected Image and Requirements]

1. I'd like to show an clipped detail of the texture while the clipping rect can be animated so I cannot crop the image upfront. The position of the image is animated too.
2. I'd like to show it in front of a background. The background is a color or a texture itself.
3. I'd like to blend both the image and the background combined with opacity 
    < 1.0 to the destination.
4. The real requirement here is to render it in one step, avoiding a temporary buffer. Obviously a (simple) shader is needed for that.

What I already tried to achieve this:

- Rendering the background first and then the image each with opacity < 1. The problem here: It lets the background shine through the image. The background is not allowed to be visible where the image itself is opaque.
- It works when rendering both into a temporary buffer using opacity = 1 and then rendering this buffer to destination with opacity < 1, but this needs more (too much) resources.
- I can combine two textures (background, image) in a shader, transform the texture coordinates each with a different transformation matrices. The probleme here is, that I'm not able to clip the image. The rendered geometry is a simple rectangle consisting of two triangles.

Can anybody hint me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically trying to render this.
(Image blended with background) blended with destination

The part in parentheses, you can do with a shader, the blending with destination, you have to do with glBlendFunc, since the destination isn't available in the pixel shader.

It sounds like you know how to clip the image in the shader and rotate it by animating texture coordinates.

Let's call your image with the childreb on it ImageA, and the grey square ImageB

You want your shader to produce this at each pixel:

```
outputColor.rgb = ImageA.rgb * ImageA.a + ImageB.rgb * (1.0 - ImageA.a);
```

This blends your two images exactly as you want. Now set the alpha output from your pixel shader to be your desired alpha (<1.0)

```
outputColor.a = <some alpha value>
```

Then, when you render your quad with your shader, set the blend function as follows.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
<draw quad>
```